# Missing maven .m2 folder

Tags: windows, maven, installation

AFAIK maven does not have an installer for Windows, you simply unzip it wherever you like, as explained [here](http://maven.apache.org/download.html).

However in many places there are references to a `.m2` folder under the user folder (in Win7 I would guess it to be by default at `C:\Users\.m2`. Alas I do not have that folder. Is there some command to create this folder? Am I missing something basic?

Comment: I would expect it to be under wherever the `java.home` Java [system property](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties%28%29) points to (by default). It will be created by Maven if it does not exist.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

On a Windows machine, the .m2 folder is expected to be located under `${user.home}`. On Windows 7 and Vista this resolves to `<root>\Users\<username>` and on XP it is `<root>\Documents and Settings\<username>\.m2`. So you'd normally see it under `c:\Users\Jonathan\.m2`.

If you want to create a folder with a `.` prefix on Windows, you can simply do this on the command line.

- Go to **Start**->**Run**
- Type **cmd** and press **Enter**
- At the command prompt type **md c:\Users\Jonathan\.m2** (or equivalent for your ${user.home} value).

Note that you don't actually need the **.m2** location unless you want to create a distinct user settings file, which is optional (see the [Settings reference](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html) for more details).

If you don't need a separate user settings file and don't really want the local repository under your user home you can simply set the location of your repository to a different folder by modifying the global settings file (located in \conf\settings.xml).

The following snippet would set the local repository to `c:\Maven\repository` for example:

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                  http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <localRepository>c:\Maven\repository</localRepository>
  ...
```

Comment: Very clear answer! tried it and it solved my problem. But you answered a different question I asked on SA. Rich, if you'll copy paste the last part of your answer to my other question, I'll give you the credit of the correct answer. The Q is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081838/how-to-set-where-maven-installs-plugins

Comment: Glad it helped, I've modified the answer slightly to better fit the other question.

Comment: Rich, I'm giving you the answer because you helped me solve my problem, although you didn't help me understand why I (still) don't have the .m2 directory...

Comment: If you want to create it from Windows Explorer, you need to create a folder with the name `.m2.`(note the trailing dot). Don't worry, windows will remove the trailing dot for you.

Answer (score 43):

When you first install maven, .m2 folder will not be present in C:\Users\ {user} path.
To generate the folder you have to run any maven command e.g. mvn clean, mvn install etc. so that it searches for settings.xml in .m2 folder and when not found creates one.

So long story cur short,
open cmd -> mvn install

It will show could not find any projects(Don't worry maven is working fine :P)
now check your user folder.

P.S. If still not able to view .m2 folder try unhiding hidden items.

Answer (score 18):

Use `mvn -X` or `mvn --debug` to find out from which different locations Maven reads settings.xml. [This switch](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3-LATEST/maven-embedder/cli.html) activates debug logging. Just check the first lines of `mvn --debug | findstr /i /c:using /c:reading`.

---

Right, Maven uses the Java system property `user.home` as location for the .m2 folder.

But `user.home` does **not always** resolve to `%USERPROFILE%\.m2`. If you have moved the location of your Desktop folder to another place, `user.home` might resolve to the parent directory of this new Desktop folder. This happens when using Windows Vista or a more recent Windows together with Java 7 or any older Java version.

The blog post [Java’s “user.home” is Wrong on Windows](http://www.timehat.com/javas-user-home-is-wrong-on-windows/) describes it very well and gives links to the official bug reports. The bug is marked as resolved in Java 8. The comment of the blog's visitor Lars proposes a nice workaround.

Comment: This answer lead me to solve my problem. In my case the maven command was run under SYSTEM account by some script. On previous server, the `.m2` was located at `C:\.m2`. But on a recent server update (with newer windows) it seems to be found on `C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.m2`

Answer (score 2):

Do you have the file system display config set up to show hidden files and folders?  If I remember correctly, by default it's hidden.  Should be under c:\users\username\.m2.

Comment: yes I do :) What should create this folder in the first place?

Comment: I believe it's created when you run your first project through maven.  Has your project built successfully, and if not how far did it make it?

Comment: no it did not due to this currently unsolved question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081275/maven-wont-download-a-plugin?answertab=oldest#tab-top

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.  Once you get that jar visible to Maven and start the build successfully, the directory should show up.

Comment: If I require a successful build start to have the .m2 directory, and only through this directory I might be able to resolve the following issue, then I'm at a deadlock - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081838/how-to-set-where-maven-installs-plugins

Comment: There is also a global settings.xml file in the conf directory of your Maven distribution to set your wanted settings (and this would be the right point for settings that apply to all users).

Comment: Following Rich Seller's answer, I was able to successfully build. Alas the .m2 directory is still missing from C:\Users\Jonathan... a mystery...

Answer (score 2):

If the default .m2 is unable to find, maybe someone changed the default path. Issue the following command to find out where is the Maven local repository,

```
mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=settings.localRepository
```

The above command will scan for projects and run some tasks.
Final outcome will be like below

[image]

As you can see in the picture the maven local repository is **C:\Users\X\.m2\repository**

Answer (score 0):

Check the configurations in {M2_HOME}\conf\setting.xml as mentioned in the following link.

http://www.mkyong.com/maven/where-is-maven-local-repository/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there some command to create this folder?

If smb face this issue again, you should know the most simple way to create **`.m2`** folder. 
If you unzipped maven and set up maven path variable - just try `mvn clean` command from anywhere you like! 
Dont be afraid of error messages when running - it works and creates needed directory.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm right, it's just because you are missing the `cd` command. Try `c:\Users\Jonathan\cd .m2/`.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to have Maven in your system.
2. Please add Maven Home or M2 Home in your Environment Variables[M2_HOME/ MAVEN_HOME]

3)Add the path of your maven in Environment Variables.

4)now open cmd and run mvn ; it will create the folder.