# How to set where maven installs plugins?

Tags: plugins, maven, installation, directory

I've tried building a project with maven 2.2.1 and received the following error
Notice the "directory cannot be created" - the reason I believe is that D: is a drive that was encrypted by TrueCrypt and is now actually H: (D: remains as a physical drive not accessible through Windows)

**How do I make maven try to install the plugin on H: instead of on D:?**

```
C:\dev\some-project>mvn -f uberPom.xml install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Declarations
[INFO]    task-segment: [install]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: http://download.java.net/maven/2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-site-plugin/2.0-beta-7/maven-site-plugin-2.0-beta-7.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:pom:2.0-beta-7' in repository maven2-repository.dev.java.net (http://download.java.net/maven/2)
Downloading: http://repo.marketcetera.org/maven/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-site-plugin/2.0-beta-7/maven-site-plugin-2.0-beta-7.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:pom:2.0-beta-7' in repository internal (http://repo.marketcetera.org/maven)
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-site-plugin/2.0-beta-7/maven-site-plugin-2.0-beta-7.pom
[WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:pom:2.0-beta-7' from repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Specified destination directory cannot be created: D:\.m2\repository\org\apache\
maven\plugins\maven-site-plugin\2.0-beta-7
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-site-plugin/2.0-beta-7/maven-site-plugin-2.0-beta-7.pom
[WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:pom:2.0-beta-7' from repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Specified destination directory cannot be created: D:\.m2\repository\org\apache\
maven\plugins\maven-site-plugin\2.0-beta-7
Downloading: http://download.java.net/maven/2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-site-plugin/2.0-beta-7/maven-site-plugin-2.0-beta-7.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:pom:2.0-beta-7' in repository java.net (http://download.java.net/maven/2)
Downloading: http://repo.marketcetera.org/maven/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-site-plugin/2.0-beta-7/maven-site-plugin-2.0-beta-7.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:pom:2.0-beta-7' in repository internal (http://repo.marketcetera.org/maven)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Error building POM (may not be this project's POM).


Project ID: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin

Reason: POM 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin' not found in repository: Unable to download the artifact from any repository

  org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:pom:2.0-beta-7

from the specified remote repositories:
  central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2),
  java.net (http://download.java.net/maven/2),
  internal (http://repo.marketcetera.org/maven),
  maven2-repository.dev.java.net (http://download.java.net/maven/2)

 for project org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin


[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] For more information, run Maven with the -e switch
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Sat May 21 14:45:51 IDT 2011
[INFO] Final Memory: 2M/46M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Means first you have changed your settings.xml to use a different location for your local repository (may be the user home is change based on the configuration in Windows which i don't know)..furthermore why are you using a different pom?

Comment: @khmarbaise - What do you mean by different pom?

Comment: Why are you using mvn -f ueberPom.xml install instead of simply mvn  install...

Comment: @khmarbaise - there are two steps to build the project - this step which is the first sets up all the Maven library dependencies that are used in the subsequent POM files, the second step actually builds the project. It's just easier that way.

Comment: May be i miss something but it sounds to me that you didn't understand Maven, cause it will handle all dependencies and download if they need to be ..?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the location of your local repository to a different folder by modifying the global settings file (located in \conf\settings.xml). Any plugins and artifacts would then be installed/downloaded to that location.

The following snippet would set the local repository to `h:\Maven\repository` for example:

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                  http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <localRepository>h:\Maven\repository</localRepository>
  ...
```