# Maven not using repository specified in %USERPROFILE%\.m2\settings.xml

Tags: maven, repository

I have specified a local repository in my settings.xml in %USERPROFILE%.m2 directory.

```
     <profile>
        <id>mainprofile</id>
        <repositories>
            <repository>
              <url>http://maven/maven2</url>
```

However when I do the maven build, it tries to download from the maven central repo

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...

Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/tiger/t-parent/4.0.1/t-parent-4.0.1.pom

[INFO] Unable to find resource 'com.tiger:t-parent:pom:4.0.1' in repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)
```

Why does this happen? Please help before I shoot myself.

Update: If I explicitly specify the option --settings=%USERPROFILE%\.m2\settings.xml in the maven command line, then it works. Why does it not use it automatically like it is supposed to?

Answer (score 1):

carefully check your pom(s) if these are free of unwanted *repository* entries. These might look like:

```
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>tiger</id>
    <name>tiger repository</name>
    <url>http://some.idiot.put.this.url.here/404.not.found</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```

Stuff like above bite me one. I'll never forget that.

Comment: I only have our local repository specified in the repositories section. There is no other repository entry. Also pleaes see my update in my question.

Comment: I see. Did you check environment for _M2_HOME_? by the way which version maven are you using?

Comment: Yes, M2_HOME is set to C:\apache-maven-2.2.1 and this is the maven version I'm using.

Comment: strange. Mine is almost the same _C:\dev\apache-maven-2.2.1_ and it works like a charm. Did you check C:\apache-maven-2.2.1\conf\settings.xml? is _localRepository_ entry commented there? it's commented by default

Comment: Yes it is commented out, I didn't touch that file. Let us give up, I will live, as I'm able to do the build by explicitly specifying the settings.xml file.

Comment: +1 for the url 'some.idiot.out.this.here' loved it and understand the frustration when we get hit with such issues with maven

Answer (score 1):

Use `mvn -X` to find out from which different locations Maven reads settings.xml. The switch activates debug logging. Just check the first lines.

---

Have you moved the folder location of your Windows desktop? In that case, `user.home` might not resolve to `%USERPROFILE%\.m2`. For details, have a look at my answer to [Missing Maven .m2 folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081617/missing-maven-m2-folder/22516000#22516000).

Answer (score 0):

Did you set a mirror?

```
<mirrors>
   <mirror>
     <!--This sends everything else to /public -->
     <id>nexus</id>
     <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
     <url>http://maven/maven2</url>
   </mirror>
</mirrors>
```

From [Sonatype's Nexus book](http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/maven-sect-single-group.html), altered url.

Comment: could you paste the complete pom?

Comment: I doubt that would help. Repository Urls are specified in the settings.xml only not in pom.xml. Also pleaes see my update in my question.

Comment: Let us give up, I will live, as I'm able to do the build by explicitly specifying the settings.xml file.