# How do I include JPA 2.1 functionality in my Maven project?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, left-join, jpa-2.0, criteria

I’m using Maven 3, JPA 2.1, and Hibernate 4.3.5.Final.  I want to use JPA 2.1 because it offers several features, most notably adding conditions to left outer join clauses.  I have included the following dependencies in my Maven project …

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>   
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.2.Final</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

However, when I try and compile the following, I get a compilation error (“cannot find symbol”) on the “.on(“ clause.

```
    final CriteriaBuilder cb = m_entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Message> query = cb.createQuery(Message.class);
    Root<Message> messageRoot = query.from(Message.class);
    final Join<Message, Group> groupJoin = messageRoot.join(Message_.group);
    final Join<Message, MessageReadDate> msgReadDateJoin = messageRoot.join(Message_.messageReads, JoinType.LEFT);
    msgReadDateJoin.on(msgReadDateJoin.get(MessageReadDate_.recipient), recipient);
```

What libraries do I need to include in my Maven project to get JPA 2.1 and hence the “join.on” functionality?

Comment: Can you include your imports as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be a maven issue. Usually happens if the jars that it downloaded are corrupted for some reason. Delete the .m2 folder repository and do `mvn install` again, it should bring all the enw jars and compilation should work.

m2 folder [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081617/missing-maven-m2-folder)

Comment: I deleted everything in my ~/.m2/org/hibernate folders, re-built, but still got the compilation error.

Comment: @Dave If using the eclipse, can you navigate the jar file and see what's in the Join.class file of the JPA jar file? Hint: Do F3 on Criteriabuilder class then Join class should be next to that if they are in the same package