# Deploying Mule application on Cloud Hub, using Azure Devops

Tags: azure, maven, azure-devops, mulesoft, cloudhub

I am trying to deploy my mule application build on anypoint studio, to cloud hub via Azure Devops.
To do so I am doing the following:

1. Created a repository on azure and upload the mulesoft application files on it. (success)
2. Started a runtime server from cloud hub using mulesoft stand alone runtime on my device(via cmd). (success)
3. create a secure file and upload setting.xml to it so that it could be used to create the pipeline.(could'nt find setting.xml file)

Hence I am not able to create the pipeline
I tried uploading an setting.xml file using the following script, but maven pom.xml throws error for it:

```
<server>
        <id>Exchange2</id>
        <username>guest-mule</username>
        <password>Mulesoft1</password>
    </server>
```

```
    <id>Mule</id>
    <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>Exchange2</id>
            <name>Exchange2</name>
            <url>https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus-ee/content/repositories/releases-ee/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
                       <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
           </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</profile>
```

Where to find the setting.xml file I tried searching it in .m2 folder in my system (also enabling the hidden items option)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the .m2 folder is in users folder, such as `c:\Users\xxx\.m2`. But it is not required, so it is make sense that there isn't .m2 folder in your system.

You could create it manually: [Missing maven .m2 folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081617/missing-maven-m2-folder)

After that you could upload this settings.xml file to Azure DevOps as secure file, then add [Download Secure File task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-secure-file?view=azure-devops) to your Azure DevOps pipeline. Then the file will be download to temp folder (`$(Agent.TempDirectory)`) during build/release.

You could specify settings.xml file for mvn commmand (-s or --settings ), more information, please call `mvn --help` to check detail options.

If you are using [Maven task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/maven?view=azure-devops) in your Azure DevOps pipeline, you could specify settings.xml file path (in temp folder) in Options box.

Comment: Thank you @starian chen-MSFT ,
I found that setting.xml file is for enterprise edition, So I changed the approach and followed this [link](https://dzone.com/articles/deploying-mule-application-to-cloudhub-via-aws-azu)
But I am getting some error while deploying the build
It would be very helpful you could give look to this
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62642637/unknown-lifecycle-phase-mvn-you-must-specify-a-valid-lifecycle-phase-or-a-go)

Comment: @RaghvendraKumar Others provided the solution for that issue.

Comment: @RaghvendraKumar For current thread, you could add an answer or [mark a solution as answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) that helped you solve your issue.