# Unknown lifecycle phase ".mainClass=com.blobs.quickstart.App"

Tags: java, azure, powershell, azure-web-app-service, blob

I ran through this demo (using PowerShell). Everything was fine until I ran the line:

mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.blobs.quickstart.App" -Dexec.cleanupDaemonThreads=false

then I got the below exception:

```
[INFO]
[INFO] --------------< com.blobs.quickstart:blob-quickstart-v12 >--------------
[INFO] Building blob-quickstart-v12 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.497 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-11-27T18:49:01-05:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase ".mainClass=com.blobs.quickstart.App". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/LifecyclePhaseNotFoundException
```

This is the link from where I followed the steps https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-java?tabs=powershell#get-the-connection-string

Comment: Anyone please this question...

Comment: Please edit your question and include the details about the SDK you’re using.

Comment: it's SDK V12 which I am using...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [ManojReddy-MSFT](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/43697#issuecomment-559731324) suggested:

In most cases, this error occurs because of the missing plugin http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/index.html

Can you verify if you have this plugin? if not, can you try with this plugin?

You can also refer to [“Unknown lifecycle phase ”mvn“. You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal” While Deploying the application using Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62642637/unknown-lifecycle-phase-mvn-you-must-specify-a-valid-lifecycle-phase-or-a-go)

Answer (score 2):

Even with the plugin I got that error message. I fixed it by changing the double quotes (I am also using Powershell):

```
mvn exec:java -D"exec.mainClass=my.main.Clazz" [other args with same quote pattern]
```